# How does docker-compose link work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have three containers, web, rest and db. I want rest (nodejs) to be able to access db (mongodb).

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
 web:
  build: front
  depends_on:
   - db
   - rest
 db:
  build: backend/mongodb
  volumes:
   - /src/docker/mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb
  restart: always
 rest:
  build: backend/rest
  restart: always
  links:
    - db:database
```

In my nodejs program:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://database:27017/mytest", function (err, db) {
 ...
```

However, my mongo client can't reach the database and keeps restarting...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Containers will be reachable by their names. So, in your case, you have to use the name of the `db` service, which is `db`:

`MongoClient.connect("mongodb://db:27017/mytest", function (err, db) {`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your node.js application is your `web` service? Web can only access the `db` service by using the hostname `db`. However the `rest` service can access it using `db` or `database` because you have given it a link alias.

You can either replicate that `links:` alias in the `web` service definition, or change your connect string to use `db` instead of `database`.

This should work right now:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://db:27017/mytest", function (err, ndb) {
```

Or with the link added:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://database:27017/mytest", function (err, db) {
```